# Postfix Cannot Receive Mail (port 25 issue)

Tags: postfix, smtp

I have configured Postfix, Dovecot, Roundcube, Fail2Ban, running on Apache and MySQL following the guide here:
https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/ubuntu-16-04-iredmail-server-installation
I installed the collection of packages on Ubuntu Server 16.04.

hostname: mail.mydomain.com

IP: 10.10.10.11

I followed the guide thoroughly but have not configured the system to received mail for more than one domain (I only need one). This server is behind a pfSense firewall with the necessary ports forwarded from my WAN IP to the mail server.

Pub.lic.ip.address -> 10.10.10.11

**The long and short is this**: I can send mail out-and-about and all-around just fine but cannot receive mail from outside the organization. 
What I have tried:

My DNS is correctly configured with A, MX, PTR, SPF and TXT records that indicate my sender domain is trust worthy and the internet can successfully find the correct mail server (received on the same IP as the root domain) and there is/are no problem(s) there (this is the #2 suggestion, it would seem, that people post on forums).

I can telnet port 25 into the server from within my LAN 10.10.10.10 -> 10.10.10.11:25

I cannot telnet into my server over port 25 from outside my domain. I know the #1 thing anyone suggests on the forums is “Your ISP must be blocking port 25” but this is not true in my case... I can change my NAT settings on pfSense to forward WAN port 25 to LAN port 587, telnet from the WAN over port 25 and successfully receive a response.

I have attached a modified main.cf (removed custom IPs and domain names for safety) and you can see within the config I have done the following:

I have modified it to include my 10.10.10.0/24 subnet

I have added the recommended settings to the mydestination =

I also found a reference to proxy/nat external network addresses and have added that to my main.cf with no change:
http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#proxy_interfaces

```
enter # location of the Postfix queue. Default is /var/spool/postfix.
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix

# location of all postXXX commands. Default is /usr/sbin.
command_directory = /usr/sbin

daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/sbin

data_directory = /var/lib/postfix

mail_owner = postfix

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail

newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases

mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq

setgid_group = postdrop

debugger_command =
    PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
    ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

debug_peer_level = 2

# SMTP server response code when recipient or domain not found.
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

# Do not notify local user.
biff = no

# Disable the rewriting of "site!user" into "user@site".
swap_bangpath = no

# Disable the rewriting of the form "user%domain" to "user@domain".
allow_percent_hack = no

# Allow recipient address start with '-'.
allow_min_user = no

disable_vrfy_command = yes

# Enable both IPv4 and/or IPv6: ipv4, ipv6, all.
inet_protocols = all

# Enable all network interfaces.
inet_interfaces = all

#
# TLS settings.
#
# SSL key, certificate, CA
#
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt

#
# Disable SSLv2, SSLv3
#
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
lmtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
lmtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3

#
# Fix 'The Logjam Attack'.
#
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, eNULL, EXPORT, DES, RC4, MD5, PSK, aECDH, EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA, EDH-RSA-DES-CDC3-SHA, KRB5-DE5, CBC3-SHA
smtpd_tls_dh512_param_file = /etc/ssl/dh512_param.pem
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/ssl/dh2048_param.pem

tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom


smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1

# Opportunistic TLS: announce STARTTLS support to remote SMTP clients, but do
# not require that clients use TLS encryption.
smtpd_tls_security_level = may

# This is disabled by default, as the information may be modified in transit
# through other mail servers. Only information that was recorded by the final
# destination can be trusted.
#smtpd_tls_received_header = yes

smtp_tls_security_level = may

# Use the same CA file as smtpd.
smtp_tls_CAfile = $smtpd_tls_CAfile
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes

#enable_long_queue_ids = yes

# Reject unlisted sender and recipient
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes

# Header and body checks with PCRE table
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
body_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/body_checks.pcre

#smtpd_command_filter = pcre:/etc/postfix/command_filter.pcre

# HELO restriction
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/helo_access.pcre
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname

# Sender restrictions
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_unknown_sender_domain
    reject_non_fqdn_sender
    reject_unlisted_sender
    check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_access.pcre

# Recipient restrictions
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_unknown_sender_domain
    reject_non_fqdn_sender
    reject_unlisted_sender
    check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_access.pcre

# Recipient restrictions
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient
    reject_unlisted_recipient
    check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777
    reject_unauth_destination

# END-OF-MESSAGE restrictions
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions =
    check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777

# Data restrictions
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining

proxy_read_maps = $canonical_maps $lmtp_generic_maps $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $mynetworks $recipient_bcc_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relay_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relocated_maps $sender_bcc_maps $sender_canonical_maps $smtp_generic_maps $smtpd_sender_login_maps $transport_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $smtpd_sender_restrictions $sender_dependent_relayhost_maps

# Avoid duplicate recipient messages. Default is 'yes'.
enable_original_recipient = no

# Virtual support.
virtual_minimum_uid = 2000
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail

# Do not set virtual_alias_domains.
virtual_alias_domains =

#
# Enable SASL authentication on port 25 and force TLS-encrypted SASL authentication.
# WARNING: NOT RECOMMENDED to enable smtp auth on port 25, all end users should
#          be forced to submit email through port 587 instead.
#
#smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
#smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
#smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

# hostname
myhostname = mail.mydomain.com
myorigin = mail.mydomain.com
mydomain = mail.mydomain.com


#       MYNETWORKS = ['xx.xx.xx.xx', 'xx.xx.xx.0/24', ...]
#
mynetworks = 10.10.10.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8, [::1]

proxy_interfaces = My.Public.IP.ADDRESS

# Accepted local emails
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost.mydomain.com, mail.mydomain.com, mydomain.com

alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases

# Default message_size_limit.
message_size_limit = 15728640

recipient_delimiter = +


compatibility_level = 2

transport_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_user.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_domain.cf

sender_dependent_relayhost_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_dependent_relayhost_maps.cf

# Lookup table with the SASL login names that own the sender (MAIL FROM) addresses.
smtpd_sender_login_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_login_maps.cf

virtual_mailbox_domains =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf

relay_domains =
    $mydestination
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_domains.cf

virtual_mailbox_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf

virtual_alias_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_maps.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/catchall_maps.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_catchall_maps.cf

sender_bcc_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_domain.cf

recipient_bcc_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_user.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_domain.cf

#
# Postscreen
#
postscreen_greet_action = enforce
postscreen_blacklist_action = enforce
postscreen_dnsbl_action = enforce
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 2
postscreen_dnsbl_sites =
    zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.[2..11]*3
    b.barracudacentral.org=127.0.0.[2..11]*2

postscreen_dnsbl_reply_map = texthash:/etc/postfix/postscreen_dnsbl_reply
postscreen_access_list = permit_mynetworks cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_access.cidr

# Require Postfix-2.11+
postscreen_dnsbl_whitelist_threshold = -2
#
# Dovecot SASL support.
#
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

#
# Amavisd + SpamAssassin + ClamAV
#
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024

# Concurrency per recipient limit.
smtp-amavis_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

/var/log/mail.log shows:

“BlahBlah daemon running” and only reports changes when I send out (which, again, works fine). The lack of log entries leads me to believe that something is preventing delivery to postfix (fail2ban?) or postfix immediately rejects the SMTP attempt because of a misconfiguration.

I don’t like posting on forums until it absolutely have to and as of now, I am totally at a loss. For some reason, port 25 is NOT accessible from anything outside my network.

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
f2b-roundcube  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https,smtp,submission,pop3,pop3s,imap2,imaps,sieve
f2b-postfix  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https,smtp,submission,pop3,pop3s,imap2,imaps,sieve
f2b-dovecot  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https,smtp,submission,pop3,pop3s,imap2,imaps,sieve
f2b-postfix  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https,smtp,submission,pop3,pop3s,imap2,imaps,sieve
f2b-nginx  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https,smtp,submission,pop3,pop3s,imap2,imaps,sieve
f2b-sshd-ddos  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap2
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain f2b-dovecot (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain f2b-nginx (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain f2b-postfix (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain f2b-roundcube (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain f2b-sshd-ddos (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

My NAT translation on pfSense is here:

I can change the rule highlighted in red to WAN_IP:25 -> LAN_IP:587 at which point I successfully telnet through port 25 and received a response. 
[image: pfsense nat]

Answer (score 1):

> I can telnet port 25 into the server from within my LAN 10.10.10.10 ->
>   10.10.10.11:25

Have you double checked the pfsense firewalling rules ?

Have you tried to run tcpdump on the pfsense firewall to check from incoming packets to outgoing packets that the NAT rules you want to apply do the job, either with the destination port set to 25 and to 587 ?

I suggest to run tcpdump both on the firewall and the server during your tests to live see the difference between the 2 tests.